# How to prune old docker images, but only for a selected container?

Tags: docker, docker-image, docker-cli

We know that `docker image prune` has a `--filter` argument that can be used to select (and remove) images older than a given number of hours (e.g.`--filter "until=7*24h"`).

We also know that `docker images` has a similar `--filter` argument that supports a `before` key (e.g. `docker images --filter "before=ubuntu:22.04"`), but that can only filter images created before a given image  or reference (not a date).

But pruning as described above would apply to *all* containers, which is rather too broad. What if we wanted to prune the "old" images more selectively, restricting the pruning to the images of just a single container (e.g. to spare older base containers, etc.)?

Answer (score 0):

I've come up with something looking ugly, but apparently rather effective.

The example below removes (forcefully) all images older than 2 weeks (the shortest period for which this implementation works - can be tweaked to any period though) of the an `mirekphd/ml-cache` container (caution: as a special case it can remove all images of this container):

```
$ MAX_WEEK_NUM=2 && REPO=mirekphd && CONTAINER=ml-cache && docker images --format "{{.ID}} {{.CreatedSince}}" --filter=reference="$REPO/$CONTAINER" | grep "[$MAX_WEEK_NUM-9999] weeks\|[1-999] months\|[1-99] years" | awk '{print $1}' | xargs docker rmi -f
```